# merge partially duplicated arrays in javascript (lodash)

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a large javascript array of some people Bought a car in different years.
the simplified array is like this:

```
const owners = [{
  name: "john",
  hasCar: true,
  yearBought: 2002
}, {
  name: "john",
  hasCar: true,
  yearBought: 2005
}, {
  name: "mary",
  hasCar: true,
  yearBought: 2015
}, {
  name: "john",
  hasCar: true,
  yearBought: 2018
}]
```

if a person has more than one car (like John in this example), there is different objects for him with different years he has bought the car. I want to merge objects belongs to each individual person and the final result should be like this:

```
const owners = [{
  name: "john",
  hasCar: true,
  yearBought: [2002, 2005, 2018]
}, {
  name: "mary",
  hasCar: true,
  yearBought: 2018
}]
```

Comment: I don't think you need Lodash for that. Simply check if the element with the given name exists and if yes, push the years to `yearsBought`, if it doesnt exist, just push the new element onto the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array and group them based on `name` first. The accumulator is an object with each unique `name` as key. If the `name` already exists, use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to push them into the array. Else, create a new key in the accumulator and set it to the current object. Then, use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of the array as an array

```js
const owners = [{name:"john",hasCar:!0,yearBought:2002},{name:"john",hasCar:!0,yearBought:2005},{name:"mary",hasCar:!0,yearBought:2015},{name:"john",hasCar:!0,yearBought:2018}];

const merged = owners.reduce((r, o) => {
  if(r[o.name])
    r[o.name].yearBought = [].concat(r[o.name].yearBought, o.yearBought)
  else
    r[o.name] = { ...o };
  return r;
},{})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `reduce`:

```js
const owners = [{name:"john",hasCar:true,yearBought:2002},{name:"john",hasCar:true,yearBought:2005},{name:"mary",hasCar:true,yearBought:2015},{name:"john",hasCar:true,yearBought:2018}];

const newOwners = Object.values(owners.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.name] = acc[curr.name] ? { ...acc[curr.name], yearBought: [].concat(acc[curr.name].yearBought, curr.yearBought) } : curr;
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(newOwners);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help using **PURE lodash functions**.. it looks clean and readable.

```js
var array = [{
  name: "john",
  hasCar: true,
  yearBought: 2002
}, {
  name: "john",
  hasCar: true,
  yearBought: 2005
}, {
  name: "mary",
  hasCar: true,
  yearBought: 2015
}, {
  name: "john",
  hasCar: true,
  yearBought: 2018
}]

function mergeNames(arr) {
  return Object.values(_.chain(arr).groupBy('name').mapValues((g) => (_.merge(...g, {
    yearBought: _.map(g, 'yearBought')
  }))).value());
}
console.log(mergeNames(array));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: This creates an `yearBought` array for `mary` as well

Comment: i believe it should be be consistent for every case, that is  in which we have a single value or multiple values for `yearBought`. In this way you can manage it easily

Answer (score 0):

You can group the items with a unique key (`name` in your case), then map the groups, and merge the items in each group:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, groupBy, map, mergeWith, concat, isUndefined } = _

const mergeDuplicates = (isCollected, key) => flow(
  pr(groupBy, key), // group by the unique key
  pr(map, group => mergeWith({}, ...group, 
    (o, s, k) => isCollected(k) && !isUndefined(o) ? concat(o, s) : s
  )) // merge each group to a new object
)

const owners = [{name:"john",hasCar:true,yearBought:2002},{name:"john",hasCar:true,yearBought:2005},{name:"mary",hasCar:!0,yearBought:2015},{name:"john",hasCar:true,yearBought:2018}]

const isCollected = key => key === 'yearBought'

const result = mergeDuplicates(isCollected, 'name')(owners)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the lodash/fp version:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, map, mergeAllWith, cond, nthArg, concat } = _

const mergeDuplicates = (isCollected, key) => flow(
  groupBy(key),
  map(mergeAllWith(cond([[
    flow(nthArg(2), isCollected),
    concat,
    nthArg(1)
  ]])))
)

const owners = [{name:"john",hasCar:!0,yearBought:2002},{name:"john",hasCar:!0,yearBought:2005},{name:"mary",hasCar:!0,yearBought:2015},{name:"john",hasCar:!0,yearBought:2018}]

const isCollected = key => key === 'yearBought'

const result = mergeDuplicates(isCollected, 'name')(owners)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```